# Removing contact from all mail groups

Tags: powershell

I want to remove the mail contact from all Groups in the "Member Of" tab. I am able to remove all MemberOf for mail contact. How can I improve the speed of the script?

```
Get-MailContact <name> | ForEach-Object { Get-ADObject $_.distinguishedname -Properties memberof } | Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ -MemberOf $_.memberof
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty optimal to me given how simple it is, only a question, why the `foreach`? Do you expect `Get-MailContact` to return multiple contacts ?

I don't have an AD I can test it against, but I'd be curious to know if "reversing" the operation by removing the member from the groups instead of removing the membership from the user could make it faster:

```
$ADContact = Get-MailContact <name> | Get-ADObject -Properties memberof 
# Loop through all the groups and remove the user from them.
foreach ($group in $ADContact.MemberOf) {Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $ADContact}
```